# Calling javascript again onclick after an alert button has been made?

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, onclick

I've an issue over here in my form.

I currently have a datepicker which calls a javascript

```
<img src="test.gif" onclick="javascript:datetimepicker('hello', 'yyyyMMdd')" style="cursor:pointer"/>
```

Which actually allows me call and click the calendar and select values.

However, I have a submit button which checks for other input values as well. After I click the submit button, if one input fails to meet the validation, an alert will be prompted

```
echo "<script> alert('Please enter something valid') </script>";
return false;
```

After I click the okay button, my javascript for the datepicker does not show the calendar anymore, can anyone advice me why is this so? Thank you.

A newbie currently learning in progress,
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with i would do it like this

```
  <script>function datepick(){javascript:datetimepicker('hello', 'yyyyMMdd');};</script><img src="test.gif" onclick="datepick();" style="cursor:pointer"/>

 echo "<script> alert('Please enter something valid'); </script>";
```

maybe it could help to post more code so we could actually run it